# How can I use execle with a va_list like execvpe?

Tags: c, exec

The version of glibc I am using does not have the `execvpe` function.  However, I need that exact functionality for what I am trying to do.  The user will pass in an argument list that is their linux command for me to run (with its argument list).  Here is what it looks like:

**foo.c**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    char * newenvp[] = ...;
    execvpe(argv[1], &argv[1], newenvp);
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
foo echo -e "Hello World.\n"
```

Is there a workaround to replace `execvpe` with `execle`?

Comment: That's unlikely, because the number of variable arguments is determined at compile time, but the size of a null-terminated array can be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved my own question.  A workaround for using `execvpe` is to use `setenv` followed by `execvp`.  I believe the functionality is the same:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    setenv("MYVAR", "MYVALUE", 1);
    /* More calls to setenv can be used if needed. */
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a case in which altering the environment variables before calling `execvp` _is not_ the same as the missing `execvpe` function.  Specifically, if the new environment alters the `PATH` variable, then `execvp` could end up executing a different program.  `execvpe` always searches the current `PATH` variable before the environment is switched.